# A Floating point expression whose value is 1 shows 0 when converted to int. How to get rid of this isuue in C++?

Tags: c++, static-cast

I need to change an expression's type from floating point to integer so as to add it to another integer variable.
The actual value of the expression is **1**.
But the expression value ((d*s)/sqrt(1+pow(s, 2))) shows **0** when changed from floating point to int.
It is giving the wrong result due to this. Why does it show 0 and how do I avoid this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    float d = sqrt(2);
    float s = sqrt(1);
    cout<<((d*s)/sqrt(1+pow(s, 2)))<<"\n";  // **prints 1**
    cout<<(int) ((d*s)/sqrt(1+pow(s, 2)));  // **prints 0**
}
```

Comment: note: indent code blocks by 4 spaces. using backticks is for inline code-style text only.

Comment: prints 1 *is not* is 1

Comment: By the way, how are you compiling so that it works with `#include <ioStream>`? C++ is case-sensitive.

Comment: @JaviV: Because some file systems are not (case-sensitive).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley oh that is interesting, I never knew about that.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: A compiler *could* still warn about a `#include` directive using the wrong case for a standard header, or even treat it as a fatal error. The argument to a `#include` directive isn't just a file name; it's mapped to a specific header or file in an implementation-defined manner. But I suspect most compilers don't bother to check (which means they don't diagnose something that causes non-portable code).

Comment: if you want the answer to be rounded and not just truncated, use `(int)(number + 0.5)`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: All correct, but I was just answering *"how are you compiling so that it works with #include <ioStream>?"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the float representation. If you print the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    float d = sqrt(2);
    float s = sqrt(1);
    cout.precision(15);
    cout<<((d*s)/sqrt(1+pow(s, 2)))<<"\n";  // **prints 1**
    cout<<(int) ((d*s)/sqrt(1+pow(s, 2)));  // **prints 0**
}
```

You will see that the first line prints 0.999999982885729. When casting to int, the number is truncated, so 0. You will have to round first. For that, change the last line:

`cout<<(int) round(((d*s)/sqrt(1+pow(s, 2))));`

And the int value will be 1.

Comment: Presumably you changed the code to print the number with more precision, but that isn't in the code you ended up putting in your answer, you just have the OP's code here as far as I can tell.

Comment: You still have `ioStream` instead of `iostream`, but good answer nonetheless.

Comment: @wolfPack88 what is wrong with me today! Thank you for pointing that out, I solved it :)

Comment: That does not happen in my compiled (g++ 4.8.2). Are you sure you removed the round statement?

Comment: Oh wait, it happends if I save a as float and then `count << (int) a;` actually, I do not have an answer for that, but that is another question.

Comment: It probably has to do with the fact that the result of the expression is a `double`, not a `float`. When you assign it to a `float`, you get a slightly different value (probably one which is rounded up to 1).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley that is it most likely, if I save a as `double` and then cast it to int it shows 0 again. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This problem doesn't occur when I assign the expression to a variable(say a) and then print the value.

```
float a = (d*s)/sqrt(1+pow(s, 2));
cout<<a;       // prints 1 
cout<<(int) a; // prints 1 again not 0
```

Still curious what difference does it make?